# Парсер email сообщений

Tags: python

Пишу парсер email писем

```
    class CustomSMTPServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):

    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
        mailto = str(rcpttos[0])

        msg = email.message_from_string(data)
        # parser subject
        subject = msg.get('Subject')

        # parser body
        if msg.is_multipart():
            for part in msg.get_payload():
                if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text' and part.get('Content-Disposition') == None:
                    msg_body = part.get_payload(decode=1)

                    print(msg_body)
        else:
            msg_body = msg.get_payload()

        send_email(mailfrom, mailto, subject, msg_body)
        return
server = CustomSMTPServer(('192.168.1.35', 25), None)
asyncore.loop()
```

Работает все хорошо, но только на латиницей.
Когда в теле письма русский текст то вылазит вот это:

```
b'\xf1\xe0\xec\xee\xe5 \xf2\xee'
```

Помогите адаптировать скрипт по русский текст.

Comment: Попробуйте переводить в юникод при помощи decode('utf-8'). А вообще это у вас вполне валидные строки получаются, просто с кодировкой разберитесь. Вообще у вас кодировка в заголовках письма должна приходить и должно получаться что-то вроде .decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8'), например

Answer (score 1):

Решилось вот так:
print(bytes(msg_body).decode('cp1251'))

Comment: как минимум, не следует жёстко прописывать кодировку, попробуйте `get_charset()`, `get_content_charset()` методы, [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15157036/4279). Также `bytes(msg_body)` выглядит подозрительно: если хочется достать text/plain части email сообщения, то можно `.walk()` метод или итераторы как показано в примере использовать.